# Not able to execute browser supported JS code in Java using Rhino

Tags: java, javascript

I am trying to execute the JS code in Java using ScriptEngine (Rhino).

I get the js code of 4 different js files at run time and store it in String variable and will invoke a method in js file using the below java code,

String result = (String)invocableEngine.invokeFunction("Execute");

I am able to see the Execute method is invoking correctly, but facing below two issues

1. Scriptengine is not able to recognize the double slash (//) value used as command line in the js file, so engine is not able to invoke the code after //
2. Also scriptengine is not able to recognize the browser parameters like window , navigator, etc,,

Is there any option to solve my issues?

Answer (score 1):

The `window`, `navigator`, `document` objects and so on, are not part of the JavaScript language, but part of the [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dom/info), which is a separate part of the web browser. The Rhino engine runs the pure JavaScript language but doesn't simulate a web browser.

To run the browser-dependent JavaScript as-is, you need additional code to mimic the browser APIs that are needed. If it needs only a few simple functions, you can easily write them yourself (in JavaScript). If it needs a more complete simulation of the browser and DOM, see [Envjs](http://www.envjs.com/doc/guides), which does exactly this, and is designed for Rhino. (Note: I've never tried it myself, though.)

[HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) might also be useful to you, or even [Greasemonkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey). (It might be possible to give a more specific answer if you explain more about where this JavaScript code comes from and your goal in running it in this way.)

I'm not sure what you mean by "double slash (//) value used as command line". A double-slash introduces a comment, not a command. Any code between // and the end of the line isn't supposed to run.